# Independent animation of each armature bone without breaking hierarchy?

Tags: animation, rigging

I have a skeleton character rigged and animated. I wanna create a "death" animation where all his bones fall to the floor. I'm going to export that to Unity (that's another problem).

I can't unparent the bones from each other because that breaks the hierarchy and I need to preserve it for the Unity export.

**Is there a way to animate each bone so that it "temporarily" isn't affected by its parent, just for one animation?** Thanks.

(I've tried replacing true parenting with "child of" constraints in Pose mode - that doesn't work unfortunately as the bones aren't considered "parented" anymore)

Comment: Make sure that no bones have the "connected" property, then use a Copy Transforms (world->world) constraint instead.

Comment: Hey Nathan, thanks. That pretty much solves it. If you post this comment as answer I will mark it solved.

Answer (score 0):

This attempted answer maybe somewhat vague but I think your solution may involve some trial and error with the functions:

1. Duplicate,
2. 'make instances real' in the [object->apply] menu
3. 'separate by loose parts' while in [edit mode]
4. physics simulations

I hope this can help, forgive me if you have already tried these :)

Best regards,
John

Comment: Thanks for answering, John. Unfortunately I need the hierarchy to stay as bones.